# Show that a L2 martingale with stationary, independent increments has a certain quadratic variation

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, martingales

I need help solving the following exercise out of chapter 1 of Karatzas, Shreve:

> **5.20 Exercise.** Suppose $X\in\mathscr{M}_2$ has stationary, independent increments, and $(\mathscr{F}_t)_t$ is the filtration generated by $X$. Show that $\langle X\rangle_t=t\mathbb{E}[X_1^2]$ for all $t\geq 0$.

My approach: I only need to show that the process $(X^2-t\mathbb{E}[X_1^2])_t$ is a martingale. Integrability and adaptedness are clear. Thus only the martingale-property is left: Let $0\leq s\leq t$, then
$$
\mathbb{E}[X_t^2-t\mathbb{E}[X_1^2]|\mathscr{F}_s] = \mathbb{E}[X_t^2|\mathscr{F}_s]-t\mathbb{E}[X_1^2]=\mathbb{E}[X_t^2-X_s^2|\mathscr{F}_s]+X_s^2-t\mathbb{E}[X_1^2].
$$
I have that $X_t-X_s$ is independent of $\mathscr{F}_s$ by independence of increments. I would like to do the following
$$
\tag{a}\mathbb{E}[X_t^2-X_s^2|\mathscr{F}_s]=\mathbb{E}[(X_t-X_s)(X_t+X_s)|\mathscr{F}_s]=\mathbb{E}[X_t^2-X_s^2].
$$
**Question 1.** Is it true that $(X_t-X_s)(X_t+X_s)$ is independent of $\mathscr{F}_s$? Can I argue in this way?

Then I would like to show that for any $r\geq 0$ the following holds: 
$$
\tag{b}\mathbb{E}[X_r^2]=r\mathbb{E}[X_1^2].
$$
As $\mathbb{E}[X_r]=\mathbb{E}[X_0]=0$ it is enough to show that $\frac{1}{\sqrt{a}}X_a\sim X_1$ (equal in distribution). But I think that this only holds for a Brownian motion but not for a general $L^2$ martingale. I would like to exploit the fact that $X$ has stationary increments, but comparing $X_r$ and $X_1$ does not yield any good.

**Question 2.** Is (b) true? If yes, how to continue?

Probably this argument is wrong and one needs to be more precise since I can't figure out, where to exploit the filtration.

**Question 3.** Where do we use that the filtration is generated by $X$?

Comment: (a) is not correct as we don't know if $X_t^2-X_s^2$ is independent of $\mathscr{F}_s$. Instead, try to express $\mathbb{E}[(X_t-X_s)^2|\mathscr{F}_s]$ in two different ways. (b) is correct: setting $f(t) = \mathbb{E}[X_t^2] = \mathbb{E}[\langle X\rangle_t]$, try showing that $f(t+s) = f(t)+f(s)$ and that $f$ is continuous. What can you say about such $f$?

Comment: @Michh thank you. I could figure out (b) now. I am still stuck with (a) though. I found out that $\mathbb{E}[X_t^2-X_s^2|\mathscr{F}_s]=\mathbb{E}[(X_t-X_s)^2|\mathscr{F}_s]$ but I don't see the other way to express this term. I tried to exploit the independence of the increments, but this yields the same. Any further hint?

Comment: Use that $X_t-X_s$ is independent of $\mathscr{F}_s$ (this follows from the independence of increments) to get $\mathbb{E}[(X_t-X_s)^2|\mathscr{F}_s] = \mathbb{E}[(X_t-X_s)^2]$.

Comment: @Michh thank you. For me it was just not clear, that $Z$ independent of $\mathscr{F}$ implies that $Z^2$ independent of $\mathscr{F}$. But looking at the definition, it is straightforward to prove it.